# Win32 Application with high CPU usage

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

It is my first time working with Windows applications and I am a bit frustrated. I just have a simple code that creates a Win32(Visual C++) GUI application, but as soon as I start the executable my CPU goes up to 30%(Over the application), in my search to solve this I have found someone saying that sleep for 10ms in the message loop(GetMessage or PeekMessage) would solve this and it indeed did. But as I don't really enjoy sleeping my code all of a sudden and by the fact that this is a event handler loop I would love an explanation on how to solve this.

A peek on the "troublesome area".

```
while (TRUE) {
    if (PeekMessage(&g_Msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        TranslateMessage(&g_Msg); // translate keystroke messages into the right format
        DispatchMessage(&g_Msg); //Send the message to the WindowProc function
        if (g_Msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;
    } else {
        // Run d3d code here
    }
    // Sleep(1); REDUCES CPU!
}
```

Thanks in advance

Caio Guedes

Comment: Using `PeekMessage` will not wait for something, so doing that in a loop will ensure that the CPU is busy all the time...

Comment: What did you expect? Your code runs as fast as it can. Obviously, this burns CPU. If you want to run it slower, then do so. The canonical solution to slowing down code is to put it to sleep. Hard to understand, why you even care about CPU consumption in an application that continuously renders content.

Comment: I undertand that Mats, but isn't the CPU usage a bit too high? If I check other applications like... VLC I can see that they do not tend to have this kind of "problem".

Comment: This is supposed to be a video player, I want the big processment part to start when the video decoding starts :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A standard Windows application loop uses GetMessage.  GetMessage blocks until there's input or something in the application that needs to run.

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

What you have coded is suitable and standard for **a game** - when you want DirectX to render frames as fast as possible while still pumping messages for other in-process windows and Win32 APIs.  What you have coded is essentially using an entire core of CPU when you code it this way.  (If you have a quad-core CPU, you're using at least 25%, so that 30% measurement seems accurate).

The periodic `Sleep(0)` or `Sleep(1)` statement is useful to allow your main thread to yield to other threads and processes.  You'll sacrifice a little frame rate, but sometimes that's necessary if the game has other threads for networking and sound.  But since you have a multi-core CPU, then you might not need to do that since the other cores can service those threads.

In the old days, before hyperthreading and multi-core, doing the `Sleep` statement was the normal way to not be a total resource hog. It allowed other background applications on Windows to be able to run.

Comment: Got it! I will proceed the code with no sleep by now! Thank you! And thanks to the others that answered.

Comment: I just noticed in the question comments that you are doing this for rendering a video player. If that's the case, you could consider having your video rendering on a separate thread and directly painting directly on the surface of the HWND/HDC you created in the main thread.  Your main thread uses GetMessage. Your rendering thread decodes video at the expected frame rate.

Comment: That is what I intended to do. Another quick question, is Direct3D the best solution for displaying the decoded frames? I am trying to reproduce videos up to 4K.

Comment: Have you looked at [Media Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: Yes I have, that is what I am using to create another player, the one I am developing right now is supposed to display raw files, so I don t want to spend a lot of time with it. Is the EVR a good solution over d3d?

Comment: Ultimately, EVR is going to render onto a DirectX surface. My understanding bout MF and EVR is that they can utilize the GPU directly for certain operations.

Comment: When rendering to a device context across threads, keep in mind that DC have a certain degree of thread affinity. You will have to manually coordinate access. See [Thread affinity of user interface objects, part 2: Device contexts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/10/11/479587.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers! I will read a bit more on the difference between them.

Comment: If you're using DirectX it can be made to synchronize with the vblank, which gives you a built-in Sleep in a fashion.

Comment: @selbie By the old days, you mean Win16 co-operative scheduling. Uniproc Win32 had preemptive scheduling.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - During the Win9x days, an application could easily  starve the rest of the processes from working sufficiently.  For example, I worked on a voice comm app that ran in the background while a full screen game in the foreground was running. We had to convince some game developers to do the `Sleep(0)` thing and not pass the realtime flags for process/thread priority, otherwise our codec thread couldn't get enough cycles.

Comment: @selbie The same can happen today though.

Answer (score -1):

You should use GetMessage(), it's a blocking function. It will block until there is something to process.

Comment: No need to state the obvious!

Comment: Why not? I write about things that are obvious to me. Apparently it wasn't obvious to you, that the code in question does implement the standard message loop of a continuously updating application. Hence, your suggestion doesn't address the question. Next time, I'll just leave it at downvoting your answer, without leaving a comment.

Comment: +1. Yes, even in an application that continuously updates. Those updates didn't belong on the GUI thread anyway. To keep the GUI responsive, the GUI thread should be ready to handle messages at all time, and being blocked in `GetMessage` is how you achieve that.

Comment: Thanks MSlaters, that's a pertinent comment.

Comment: @MSalters: Games usually put rendering and message processing on the same thread. For one, there are extremely few messages arriving, and when e.g. a resize request comes in, it's best to recreate device resources on the same thread. That way you get serialization for free. If a game does use keyboard input messages, it doesn't matter whether rendering happens on the same thread or not. If rendering were to slow down input processing, then it is also too slow to promptly display the result. Placing slow rendering on another thread buys you nothing.